# Add time strata variable and change format in r

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have tried to get an answer to this with no luck. Hopefully someone out there can assist me. I have a data set of patients.

```
PatientID <- c('1', "1", "1","1", "2","2","2","2","3","3","3","3")
admission.duration.minutes <- c(0,0.5,1.2,2,0,2.5,3.6,8,0,4,22,24)
has.fever <- c(1,1,NA,0,1,NA,1,1,NA,0,1,NA)
on.ventilator<-c(1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,NA,1,0,NA)
high.bloodpressure<-c(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,NA,1)
df <- data.frame(PatientID, admission.duration.minutes, has.fever,on.ventilator,high.bloodpressure)
```

I want to change the dataset so I have one line per patient and I want to calculate how many patients had fever in hour 1, on ventilator in hour 1, high blood pressure in hour 1, combinations of fever and ventilator and blood pressure in hour 1. The same for hour 2, 3, etc.

So I believe I first need to add a time strata variable that defines hour 1, 2, 3 etc. So Hour 1 = 0.0 - 1.0 and Hour 2 is >1.0 to 2.0. And then do a conditional count or something like that.

I have tried with the publish package, but cannot get the output right.

The output from the new data frame should look something like this:

```
PatientID       hour1.fev   hour1.vent  hour1.BP    hour1.fev&vent  hour1.fev&BP    
1               1           1           1           1               1
hour1.vent&BP   hour2.fev   hour2.vent  hour2.BP    hour2.fev&vent  hour2.fev&BP
1               0           1           0           1               1 
hour2.vent&BP
1
```

Can you help me?

[Current data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGhe4.jpg)

[How the new dataframe could look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AGCa.jpg)

Comment: Could you please clarify were are the hours in your data? Does every data piece for each patient correspond to a certain hour?

Comment: The variable admission.duration gives the length of the admission when the other variables have been recorded. So if admission.duration for example is 2.5 and the has.fever is 1 it means the patient has been to the hospital for 2.5 hours and has a fever.

Comment: The variables has been recorded at different timepoints, but the duration in hospital is recorded whenever a variable is recorded.

Comment: The idea was therefore to add a time strata variable based on admission.duration so that when admission duration was between 0.0 and 1.0 that would equal hour 1. >1 and 2.0 would be hour 2 and so forth.

Comment: Are `admission.duration.minutes` time points? So patient 2 had high blood pressure when admitted (time 0); 2.5 hours after admission he didn't have high bloodpressure, etc. In this case what should `hour2.BP` be? We don't have data for hour2.

Comment: admission.duration.minutes are timepoints. It is calculated as time since entry into the hospital. So whenever a nurse has registered the blood pressure it is measured at a specific time so I know how long the patient has been to the hospital when that blood pressure was measured.

Comment: Sorry. Admission.duration is in hours not minutes, but that I can easily change.

Comment: Sorry. Admission.duration is in hours not minutes, but that I can easily change. Patient 1 does not have data for hour 2 because he/she was discharged. So that should just be NA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an initial approach I would propose the following way. First of all, group the data by the patients and the time spans

```
library("dplyr")
# definition of time spans
df$strata <- if_else(df$admission.duration.minutes == 0, 1, ceiling(df$admission.duration.minutes))
# note that NA measurments are silently transformed here to zeros
df_groupped <- df %>% group_by(PatientID, strata) %>% summarise_at(vars(has.fever:high.bloodpressure), 
    sum, na.rm = TRUE)
```

If we want to process NA in another way, the solution may be

```
# the result is NA only if all parameters in the strata are NA
df_groupped <- df %>% group_by(PatientID, strata) %>% 
    summarise_at(.vars = vars(has.fever:high.bloodpressure), 
        .funs = funs(if (all(is.na(.))) NA else sum(., na.rm = TRUE)), 
        na.rm = FALSE)
```

So, we obtain the grouped data frame in a long format

```
# transform numbers of measurments to booleans
df_groupped <- df_groupped %>% mutate(
    has.fever = as.integer(as.logical(has.fever)),
    on.ventilator = as.integer(as.logical(on.ventilator)),
    high.bloodpressure = as.integer(as.logical(high.bloodpressure)),
    # ".and."" means `*` instead of `+`
    fev.and.BP = as.integer(as.logical(has.fever * high.bloodpressure)),
    fev.and.vent = as.integer(as.logical(has.fever * high.bloodpressure))
)
```

Then create a function to generate a data frame of a desired structure:

```
fill_form <- function(periods, df_Patient, n_param){
    # obtain names of the measured parameters & the first column
    long_col_names <- names(df_Patient)[-(1:2)]
    long_df_names <- sapply(function(i) paste("hour", periods[i], ".", long_col_names, sep =""), X = periods)
    # add the names of the first column with the Patient's ID
    long_df_names <- c(names(df_Patient)[1], long_df_names)
    long_df <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 1, ncol = 1 + length(periods) * n_param))
    names(long_df) <- long_df_names
    long_df[, 1] <- as.character(df_Patient[1, 1])
    for (i in seq(along.with = periods)) {
        if (nrow(filter(df_Patient, strata == periods[i])) > 0) {
            long_df[ ,(2 + n_param * (i - 1)):(2 + n_param * i)] <- filter(df_Patient, strata == periods[i])[-(1:2)]
        }
    }
return(long_df) 
}
```

And then finely apply this function to the data of each individual patient

```
# the ID's of the patients extracted from the initial df
PatientIDs_names <- unique(unlist(lapply(df["PatientID"], as.character)))
n_of_patients <- length(PatientIDs_names)
n_monit_param <- (ncol(df_groupped) - 2)
# outputted periods are restricted for demonstration purposes
hours_to_monitor <- c(1:5)
records <- lapply(function(i) fill_form(periods = hours_to_monitor, 
    df_Patient = filter(df_groupped, PatientID == PatientIDs_names[i]), n_param = n_monit_param), 
    X = seq(along.with = PatientIDs_names))
```

Hope, it'll be helpful. However, I'm not sure about two things:

1) Both `hour2.fev` and `hour2.BP` are `0` in your output example, so why `hour2.fev&vent` is `1`?

2) Why `high.bloodpressure` is 0 for the `PatientID == 1` on the second time span? There is a `high.bloodpressure == 1` at time `1.2` hours. This time should be included into the second time span (Hour2 between 1 and 2), shouldn't it?

Comment: Hi Ekatef. That is very impressive. I think you solution could work. When I use it on my test-data set it works, but when I do it on the big dataset I get an error message when trying to perform the last third part of your code filling the form. It says  Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : Result must have length 24, not 12

Comment: I have the strata and the fever (1/0), fever&BP (1/0) etc. etc. but still with every patient on multiple lines. So the last part is to make it in to wide format with one line per patient. I am not sure I understand the fill_form function you use. Is PatientID==1 because the first patient is called 1?

Comment: One more thing - NAs are changed to zeros in the first part of the code, but I believe it should stay as NA so that fever&BP would then also be NA if one value was NA.

Comment: The fist problem was due to `X = 1:3` in the lapply function; I have replaced it with a more general `seq(along.with = PatientIDs_names)` in the updated answer

Comment: The result of `fill_form()` is a data frame with a single string (very long!) and the columns `hour1.has.fever`,  `hour1.on.ventilator` ... `hour1.fev.and.vent`; `hour2.has.fever`,  `hour2.on.ventilator` ... `hour2.fev.and.vent` etc. Each column contains the corresponding parameters (has.fever etc) for each time span (1 to the last of `hours_to_monitor`). When you run `fill_form()` using `lapply()`, you obtain a list where each element is such a data frame. I have modified `fill_form()` to add the Patient's ID as the first column of the data frame

Comment: Yes, `PatientID==1`means that the data for the first patient are processed. However, it was just a part of my testing not intended for the final answer. Sorry for that, now I have cleaned it up

Comment: As for NA: could you please give a little more details about the desired rules? E.g., `has.fever == c(1, 0, NA)` in `df` should the `has.fever` in the resulted data frame be `1` or `NA`?

Comment: Sorry, I will clarify. If one of the components for the fev.and.BP is NA then fev.and.BP is NA

Comment: If has.fever is 1 during hour 1, even if NA at another point during hour 1 then has.fever is still 1 for hour 1.

Comment: I think I have figured most of it out Ekatef, but I am little unsure about the final list called records. I need to change it back into a dataframe? Also, my PatientIDs have been turned into numbers (1,2,3 etc.) but in the original dataset the ID is a 10-digit number. Is there a way to keep the original ID??

Comment: @Lars Grønlykke I have updated a solution to handle NA measurements more precisely. Hope, it'll be helpful

Comment: As for ID's, you have set them as characters (with the quotes in definition of the `PatientID` vector); then they were transformed to factors in the definition of `df` according to defaults of `data.frame()`. However, I have transformed them back to characters in the final data frame --
 you may check it by `typeof(records[[1]]$Pat)`

Comment: I have used a list as an output format for as an example only. It's up to you how to use `fill_form()`.

Comment: Let me know please if my answer was helpful. If yes, then mark it please as an answer ;)

Comment: I'm glad to help you!

Comment: It seems the fill_form puts every ID in the same row so the output becomes one very long row. It would be more useful if each ID had its own row. Is that possible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165230/discussion-between-ekatef-and-lars-gronlykke).